# PostgreSQL - error when performing not in

Tags: sql, postgresql

here is the table:

```
create table video_call (
timestamp timestamp,
callerid int,
receiverid int,
call_length int);

insert into video_call values
('2018-12-12 01:01:01', 1, 2, 3),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 1, 3, 5),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 2, 4, 3),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 5, 6, 3),
('2019-01-02 01:01:01', 3, 4, 3),
('2019-01-03 01:01:01', 3, 5, 3),
('2019-01-04 01:01:01', 3, 7, 3);
```

Now I'd like to get the new users on day `2019-01-01`. Here is my answer:

```
select user from
(select distinct callerid as user from video_call where to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2019-01-01'
union
select distinct receiverid as user from video_call where to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2019-01-01') as t
where user not in 
(select distinct callerid as user from video_call where to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') < '2019-01-01'
union
select distinct receiverid as user from video_call where to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') < '2019-01-01');
```

then get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: name = integer
LINE 5: where user not in 
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 250
```

any idea of this? I already checked that all the subqueries work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word which resolves to the name of the currently logged-in PostgreSQL user.  You can see this by doing something like:

```
select user from
(select distinct callerid as user from video_call where to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2019-01-01') as t;
  user  
--------
 jjanes
 jjanes
 jjanes
```

To have it refer to a table column alias spelled "user", you need to qualify it with a table name, or put it in double quotes, or better yet just spell it differently to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
select v.userid
from video_call vc cross join lateral
     (values (vc.callerid), (vc.receiverid)) v(userid)
where timestamp < '2019-01-02'
group by v.userid
having min(timestamp) >= '2019-01-01';
```

It seems like a much simpler approach and should get around your syntax issues.

Comment: This approach is very cool! but I'm not familiar with `lateral`. Is that an in-built function?

Comment: when I run your solution, I get this error: ERROR:  
syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 3:      (values (vc.callerid), (vc.receiverid)) v(user)
                                                                               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 100
then I change user to users and it works!

Comment: Did some research and looks like lateral is SQL foreach and it can access to the query result preceding it. and values can create tmp table without insert. Learned a lot from your solution. Thanks @Gordon Linoff!

Comment: `user` is a Postgres reserved word.  You shouldn't use it as a column name.  I just figured it was a name used only in the question.